# How to run Github Actions with the 'deployment_status' kitty and only on the QAS branch?

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, cypress, github-actions, e2e

I need github actions to run only on the QAS branch and deploy event. It should run on 'pull_request' and 'pull' and only on the QAS branch.

```
name: Cypress

on: [deployment_status]

jobs:
  e2e:
    if: github.event.deployment_status.state == 'success'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Print URL
        run: echo Testing URL ${{ github.event.deployment_status.target_url }}

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2-beta
        with:
          node-version: 14

      - name: Install modules
        run: yarn

      - name: Run Cypress
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
```

But I wanted something like this:

```
name: Cypress
    
    on:
      deployment_status:
        pull_request:
          branches:
            - qas
        push:
          branches:
            - qas
    
    jobs:...
```

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to achieve what you want using triggers conditions alone. This is due to the fact that those conditions are configured to work as `OR` and not as `AND`.

It that case, a workaround is to use one trigger condition - *for example the `on: [deployment_status]` you are currently using* - then add a filter at the job level to check the branch name based on the `github.ref` from the [Github Context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context).

In your case, I guess it would look like this:

```yaml
name: Cypress

on: [deployment_status]

jobs:
  e2e:
    if: ${{ github.event.deployment_status.state == 'success' && github.ref == 'refs/heads/qas' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      [...]
```

*Note: Let me know if the `job if condition` is working as expected (I don't have a poc repo with a webhook configured to try it with the `github.event.deployment_status.state` as well).*

*Note 2: It may not be necessary to use the `${{ }}` around the condition:*

```yaml
if: github.event.deployment_status.state == 'success' && github.ref == 'refs/heads/qas'
```

Comment: This way it doesn't work in case I'm doing a `pull_request` from a branch in QAS or a `push` on that branch in `pull_request`. In the case of a `pull_request` or a `push` in this `pull_request` on a branch it is not QAS but the name of the branch I created for `pull_request`, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. However, you can always add other conditions to the `if` based on each situation to check if it match your context. It's not always elegant, but it does the job (it's a workaround).