# github workflow only on deployment_status AND specific branch

Tags: github, github-actions, vercel

Similar tho this question [How to run Github Actions with the 'deployment_status' kitty and only on the QAS branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68938451/how-to-run-github-actions-with-the-deployment-status-kitty-and-only-on-the-qas)
I want to execute a workflow only on a specific branch but combined with the `deployment_status` trigger.

So I want to execute my end to end test only if the deployment is done and we are on the `develop` branch.

The problem here is: On the trigger `deployment_status` the `github.ref` variable is not set. It is also written in docs. So I can not do a manual check if I am on the right branch.

```
name: E2E

on:
  deployment_status:
    # does not work because it is ignored on deployment_status
    branches:
      - develop
      - stage
      - master
      - main

jobs:
  chrome:
    if: github.event.deployment_status.state == 'success'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Run Cypress
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          browser: chrome
          cache-key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
        env:
          CYPRESS_BASE_URL: ${{ github.event.deployment_status.target_url }}
```

On the other way: If i use the `deployment_status` trigger I can not use `branches` or `branches-ignore` in combination. This is not working at all.

```
name: E2E

on:
  deployment_status:

jobs:
  chrome:
    # does not work because github.ref is not defined
    if: github.event.deployment_status.state == 'success' && github.ref == 'refs/heads/develop' /
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Run Cypress
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          browser: chrome
          cache-key: ${{ runner.os }}-yarn-${{ hashFiles('**/yarn.lock') }}
        env:
          CYPRESS_BASE_URL: ${{ github.event.deployment_status.target_url }}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Looks like the variable `github.event.deployment.environment` give me at least the environment from vercel. So I know if this was a `preview` build or an `production` build.